# How to add Comment Like instagram Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, state, comments

i don't know how to create state addComment and return Widget went i press button

[image]

i don't how to return ListTile with val in

```
List<CommentDetail> comments = [
    CommentDetail(
        otherUsername: "b-akused02",
        otherUserProfileImageUrl: Utils.getRandomImageUrl(),
        comment: "Nice Nice Nice Nice Nice Nice",
        date: "3 days"),
  ];
```

here is my failure code

```
    class CommentsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CommentsPageState createState() => _CommentsPageState();
}

class CommentDetail {
  String comment;
  String otherUsername;
  String otherUserProfileImageUrl;
  String date;
  CommentDetail(
      {@required this.comment,
      @required this.otherUsername,
      @required this.otherUserProfileImageUrl,
      @required this.date});
}

class _CommentsPageState extends State<CommentsPage> {
  List<CommentDetail> comments = [
    CommentDetail(
        otherUsername: "b-akused02",
        otherUserProfileImageUrl: Utils.getRandomImageUrl(),
        comment: "Nice Nice Nice Nice Nice Nice",
        date: "3 days"),
  ];
  var txt = TextEditingController();

  void _addComment(String val) {
    setState(() {
      comments.add(val);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildCommentList() {
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < comments.length) {
        return _buildCommentItem(comments[index]);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _buildCommentItem({
    @required String comment,
    @required String otherUsername,
    @required String otherUserProfileImageUrl,
    @required String date,
  }) {
    return ListTile(//comment box inside),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there 
What you are passing in the _buildCommentItem function is an object of CommentDetail.
Also, after receiving CommentDetail object, all you need to do is populate ListTile like you usually do.

```
 Widget _buildCommentList() {
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < comments.length) {
        return _buildCommentItem(commentDetail: comments[index]);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _buildCommentItem({
    @required CommentDetail commentDetail
  }) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(commentDetail.comment),
    );
  }
```